# PWA обновление иконки

Tags: javascript, html, css, pwa

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Всем привет! Подскажите, как я могу обновить иконку на iOS и Android, PWA приложения, изменив иконку в manifest. Неважно сколько по времени это займет (обновление), главное что есть ли способ? Код? Браузер сам обновит? Или какой еще вариант?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для обновления иконки на iOS и Android, PWA приложения, необходимо следующее:

1. Изменить иконку в файле manifest.json. Для этого откройте файл manifest.json в любом текстовом редакторе и замените ссылку на старую иконку на ссылку на новую иконку.
2. Загрузить новую иконку на сервер или хостинг, где находится ваше приложение.
3. Очистить кэш браузера на устройстве, на котором установлено приложение.
4. Перезапустить приложение. В большинстве случаев браузер автоматически обновит иконку приложения.
5. Если иконка не обновилась, то попробуйте перезагрузить устройство.
6. Если после всех этих действий иконка все еще не обновилась, то возможно, что браузер не поддерживает автоматическое обновление иконки. В этом случае вам придется попросить пользователей удалить старое приложение и установить новое с обновленной иконкой.

Comment: Не работает, к сожалению, так пробовал

Comment: соответствующие мета-теги ставили для iOS?

Comment: Вы про app comparable ? Да. После изменения манифеста, только  поменялась на иконку, когда обычно загрузка приложения идет, добавил к посту, причем я просто инвертировал цвета на иконке и добавил в конец пути иконки /icon.png?v0.1

Comment: так пробовали?: 
Apple Touch Icon Precomposed:
<link rel="apple-touch-icon-precomposed" href="/apple-touch-icon-precomposed.png"/>
Apple Touch Icon:
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="/apple/icon.png">

Comment: или вот: https://gist.github.com/miguelmota/b874f287a77d96034b26a68ab56280f5
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html

Comment: Попробую, пока нет

Comment: Проверил, все точно так же, ничего не меняется

Comment: У вас собственная аутентификация ?

Comment: Воспользуйтесь: https://webkit.org/blog/13966/webkit-features-in-safari-16-4/
возможно искали: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49568333/pwa-icons-are-not-used-in-ios-11-3

Comment: Вероятнее всего, это может быть связано из за версии Safari

Comment: Дайте знать, если у вас получится)

Comment: Читал апи, скорее всего из-за версии сафари, верно, не получилось к сожалению, пробовал на localhost и на хостинге